# Apps Script: Increase time by 30 mins

Tags: google-apps-script

I guess I am getting too tired and should jump into bed instead of drinking more coffee. Anyway, all I want to do is increase the current output (so, **13:30**) of the variable below by 30 mins. Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks :).

`let startTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[0][6]), 'GMT+1', 'HH:mm');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
let startTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date(data[0][6]).getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000)), 'GMT+1', 'HH:mm');
```

- In this case, 30 minutes are added to `new Date(data[0][6])`. If `data[0][6]` is the date object, you can modify it as follows.

  ```
    Utilities.formatDate(new Date(data[0][6].getTime() + (30 * 60 * 1000)), 'GMT+1', 'HH:mm')
  ```

Comment: It´s always a pleasure to read answers from you, because they are clear, precise and contain all the details required to learn more about apps script. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Bob Hardball Thank you for replying. If that was useful for you, I'm glad.